# why publishing sites based templates lose their default page?

Tags: publishing-site, 404, site-template

I'm using SP 2010, created a site based on publishing site which I modified with lists, masterpages...

then I created a template from that site.
WHen using that template to create a new site I get no default page resulting in a 404 error when first visiting the site.

I tried the same scenario with team sites which worked perfect.

What's the problem with publishing based templates?

thanks

Comment: Did you save site content when you saved the template?

Comment: Yes I did, BTW, I saved the template through the designer

Answer (score 3):

Creating a template from Publishing sites is not supported as the templating function relies heavily on content types and other items that may not be available when you create a new site from the template.

Like you I've tried the workaround from 2007 by navigating directly to the Template creation page, which does work, but I've never succeeded in then deploying a site properly based on it.

I also wouldn't do this in a production environment as you'll leave yourself short on support options if you ever have to call Microsoft.

If you do want Publishing sites set-up in a certain way, your best bet is to use features that configure the site on activation in the manner that you need. (custom code)

Paul.